# OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine xxx is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can't find the solution.
I'm having the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_process_upload_log`(
inout prm_upload_id int,
prm_location_id integer,
prm_week_start integer,
prm_error_code integer,
prm_last_attempt_date integer,
prm_error_log_url varchar(256))
BEGIN 
select null from dual;
-- real impementation is ommited, it's not an issue, im sure
end
```

and corresponing php code:

```
  function update_log($conn, $upload_id, $location_id, $errcode, $att_date, $err_url) {
    $week = 1;
    $sql = "call sp_process_upload_log (:p0,:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,:p5);";
    try {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':p0', $upload_id, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':p1', $location_id); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':p2', $week); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':p3', $errcode); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':p4', $att_date); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':p5', $err_url); 

        if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
          post_msg ("PDO Error: ".var_dump($stmt->errorInfo())."\n");
          return false;
        }
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
       post_msg ("Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
       return false;
    }
    return $upload_id;
  }

//$conn variable is assigned with db connection resource properly
  $upload_id = update_log($conn, false, 1, false, time(), "someurl");
```

It fails with the error:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "42000"
  [1]=>
  int(1414)
  [2]=>
  string(125) "OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine hex_tvdb.sp_process_upload_log is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger"
}
```

Even when trying to call for that stored procedure in MySQL Query Browser getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see this comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#101993 ? See also http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,167022,222800#msg-222800.

Comment: yes, thanks, i've found it too) it's actually a workaround. just decided to ask here while looking for the solution

Comment: Unfortunately, if your DBA restricts user variables (for any of a number of security reasons) this solution is worthless.