# Binary output parameters - PHP, PDO, MySQL: result is always null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL stored proc that returns a UUID via an output parameter. I'm calling this proc from PHP using PDO - but I'm just getting null back for the output param...  There's no explicit binary option for the output data type (PDO::PARAM_???) - the closest I guess is LOB.  Does anyone know how to do this?Here's my PHP code:

```
public function CreateTenant($name)
{
    $qry = $this->conn->prepare("call spInsertTenant(:name, :userId, :id)");
    $qry->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $qry->bindParam(':userId', $this->currUser);
    $qry->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 16);
    try {
        $qry->execute();
        return $id;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ok - the original proc is pretty long.  Here's a combination of MySQL and PHP I knocked up that is having the same problem.  Note - there's nothing inserted into my table - even though no errors are thrown.  Thanks Mihai for the nod towards declaring the $vars first...  Tried that without any luck.  Also trincot - my UUIDs are definitely binary - they're using this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

Here's the stored proc:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tenant2` (
  `ID` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));

drop procedure if exists spInsertTenant2;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInsertTenant2`(pName nvarchar(45), out oId binary(16))
begin

    set @id = ordered_uuid(uuid());

    insert  Tenant2 (ID, Name)
    values  (@id, pName);

    set oId = @id;

end$$
delimiter ;

call spInsertTenant2('Test', @id);
select * from Tenant2;
select @id, hex(@id);
```

And here's some PHP to hook into this:

```
...
// Create connection
$this->conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $this->database . ';host=' . $this->servername, $this->username, $this->password);
...

function testParam()
{
    try {
        $name = 'SomeName';
        $id = 0;
        $qry = $this->conn->prepare('call spInsertTenant2(:name :id)');
        $qry->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $qry->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
        $qry->execute();
        print $id;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note the connection to the DB is working - I'm able to execute select statements and get data back no probs.

Comment: `':name'` remove the quotes. check for errors here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have triggered that error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Thanks Fred - removing those quotes helped, BUT - I'm still not getting a value back from the output parameter in the proc.  As per your suggestion I've added try / catch - the code is not throwing any exceptions...

Comment: As fred ii says, binding values to a prepare auto escapes the values. While MySQL generously accepts quoted integers others do not unless defined `PDO::TYPE`

Comment: Yep - I get the quotes thing...  It's the binary output parameter I'm stuck on.

Comment: bindParam passes by reference so you need the variable already existing BEFORE passing Create the variable at the  beginning of the function`$var=$this->currUser;` and pass $var insted

Comment: Are you sure your UUID is binary? If it corresponds to a call to MySql's [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), function then the data type is string. So you would use `PDO::PARAM_STR` and length 36. However, you'll have maybe better results without specifying length, and passing for options: `PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`

Comment: Could you provide the declaration of your Stored procedure to see how you have typed the third parameter?

Comment: @MattWales Try it without the custom `testParam()` - `CreateTenant()` functions. If it works, then it's a variable scope issue.

Comment: @MattWales but this `spInsertTenant2(:name :id)` there should be a comma in there `spInsertTenant2(:name, :id)` and use the error checking links I left up there.

Comment: Hey @Fred -ii- Thanks - I had added a try/catch but hadn't set the exception attributes against the connection so they'd actually catch.  After doing this (and fixing the comma) I'm getting "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 2..." - seems a few other people have had this, and it's nothing to do with binary or otherwise; rather, the official PDO documentation doesn't work.  The workaround involves a second round trip to the DB server - not ideal. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,167022,222800#msg-222800.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattWales You're welcome and am glad to see you've found your solution Matt, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't to do with the type of parameters - the PDO documentation on this topic is incorrect.  The following posts describe the workaround.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,167022,222800#msg-222800 and
[OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine xxx is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240167/out-or-inout-argument-1-for-routine-xxx-is-not-a-variable-or-new-pseudo-variable).